# bash: reading text from a string one character at a time, with whitespace

Tags: bash, char, sleep, ifs

I'm bored, and decided to write a script for a text-based adventure of mine using bash. Basically, it's supposed to animate a typewriter in certain cases for dramatic storytelling. I can do this manually in a file like so:

```
sleep 0.1 
echo -n "h"
sleep 0.1 
echo -n "e"
sleep 0.1 
echo -n "l"
sleep 0.1 
echo -n "l"
sleep 0.1 
echo -n "o"
```

As you can imagine, it's dreadfully tedious. Instead, I want to pull characters from a string (or file) one character at a time, and apply the sleep command to each character.

So far, I have the following, that reads from a file. IFS= allows the spaces to retain, but not any other type of whitespace (such as newline).

```
IFS=
while read -n1 achar
do
   echo $achar
done < aFile
```

Is there a way I can use this to get all whitespace? As a bonus question, can you tell me how to apply this to a user-defined script, so I don't have to read from a separate file? So, for example, lets say I have a string called "hello", and I can simply pass it to my function to animate as a typewriter whenever I run my file in the bash terminal.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about converting newlines to spaces using `tr(1)`?

Comment: If I understand the man page correctly, do I use the tr[:print:] option?

Comment: +1 just because you decided to fight boredom with bash-scripting :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about

```
#!/bin/bash

function typewriter
{
    text="$1"
    delay="$2"

    for i in $(seq 0 $(expr length "${text}")) ; do
        echo -n "${text:$i:1}"
        sleep ${delay}
    done
}


typewriter "Typewriters are cool." .1
echo # <-- Just for a newline
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is exactly what I needed. I'm still learning the syntax for shell scripting, so this helps a lot.

Comment: No problem shell scripting is fun :-)

Comment: @derp: No need for the external `seq` and `expr` utilities: `for ((i = 0; i < ${#text}; i++))`

Comment: That makes it look more like c++, which I am used to. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, you need to use an empty delimiter as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
getc() {
  IFS= read -r -n1 -d '' "$@"
}

typewriter() {
  while getc ch; do
    sleep 0.1; echo "$ch"
  done
}
```

Basically, `read` will stop at newlines (the default delimiter) even if it hasn't consumed enough characters yet.  The `-r` flag also tells it to leave backslashes alone.

Full explanation here: http://jayferd.us/posts/2011-01-12-bash-adventures-read-a-single-character-even-if-its-a-newline

Answer (score 0):

@derp no you need to use `tr -s [:blank:]` to squeeze multiple blanks to a single one.

HTH.